# Sitecore Experience Profile slow to load

Tags: experience-profile, performance-optimization

Using Sitecore 8.2 Update 4, Sitecore Experience Profile is not loading (the spinner keeps on spinning) on our Staging server using a Lucene index. This was working fine last week and i guess, it appears to be an intermittent issue.

I've checked the Log and Crawling log - no entries

Memory useage - 73%

CPU useage - increases to ~50% and holds steady

SQL Profiler isn't showing a massive load: Mainly calls to the `EventQueue` table

I can search for individuals by name or email in the Experience Profile, and that is quick. Any suggestions on how to diagnose this, would be highly appreciated.

I have rebuilt the Analytics index using **AnalyticsIndexBuilder** tool but this had no effect.

Let me know, if more information is required.

Comment: Experience Profile uses Sitecore Analytics Index (either Lucene or Solr depending on your configuration) for the first page (Dashboard) and then heavily relies on MongoDB queries. It sounds that you have a problem with loading the Dashboard. You should check if Lucen/Solr indexes are available and that queries can be executed. Lucene index can be opened with Luke, Solr index can be queried using Solr UI.

Comment: Can you verify if you have default css file present in your Staging server?, i have seen the similar issue and resolved it by adding the missing default.css file and xsl folder.

Comment: Css and xsl seems to be there and the issue is intermittent so I dont think it's related. I can open the index in Luke OK and I've done a basic query without any issues so still not sure what the issue is

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the issue was an Out of Memory issue.

Sitecore have supplied us with a hotfix: https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/sxazbl7s4p02t19x5j6ydh8q7j4u0mvl

Comment: This worked for me too on the same issue.